# How to split a string with newlines

Tags: ios, nsstring, newline

I read from a csv file, and want to split the long string that I get using stringWithContentsOfFile, which is a multi line string, with individual lines representing rows in the csv file. How do I do this?

Comment: Why load the whole file into memory?  That won't help your memory footprint any...

Comment: Maybe it's known that the file won't be that big. It *is* just text...

Comment: yeah...the file is small enough...it has only 54 rows and 4 columns!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can break the string into arrays of string and then manipulate as you want.

```
NSArray *brokenByLines=[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]
```

Comment: This makes a LOT of assumptions about what the line separators are.

Comment: If you don't know what the line separators are: `let lines = stringData.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r\n", withString: "\"n").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r", withString: "\n").componentsSeparatedByString("\n")`

Comment: One do not have to replace @"\r", if the string is separated with newLineCharacterSet;

Answer (score 43):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this question like I did. This will work with any newline characters:

```
NSCharacterSet *separator = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *rows = [yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator];
```

Comment: This can produce empty strings in the array if the line separators are `\r\n` (two characters) as happens in Windows formatted files.

Answer (score 22):

You should be aware that `\n` is not the only character used to split a new line. For example, if the file was saved in Windows, the newline characters would be `\r\n`. Read [the Newline article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for more information about this.

Thus, if you just use `componentsSeparatedByString("\n")`, you may get unexpected results.

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\n"
let lineArray = multiLineStringRN.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
// ["Line 1\r", "Line 2\r", "Line 3\r", ""]
```

Note both the residual `\r` and the empty array element.

There are several ways to avoid these problems.

## Solutions

**1. `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`**

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
let lineArray = multiLineString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(newlineChars).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

If `filter` were not used, then `\r\n` would produce an empty array element because it gets counted as two characters and so separates the string twice at the same location.

**2. `split`**

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
let lineArray = multiLineString.utf16.split { newlineChars.characterIsMember($0) }.flatMap(String.init)
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

or

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let lineArray = multiLineString.characters.split { $0 == "\n" || $0 == "\r\n" }.map(String.init)
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

Here `\r\n` gets counted as a single Swift character (an extended grapheme cluster)

**3. `enumerateLines`**

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
var lineArray = [String]()
multiLineString.enumerateLines { (line, stop) -> () in
    lineArray.append(line)
}
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

For more about the `enumerateLine` syntax, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096185/3681880) also.

## Notes:

- a multi line string would not usually mix both `\r\n` and `\n` but I am doing this here to show that these methods can handle both formats.
- [`NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/newlineCharacterSet) are newline characters defined as (U+000A–U+000D, U+0085), which include `\r` and `\n`.
- This answer is a summary of the answers to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021712/how-to-split-a-string-by-new-lines-in-swift). Read those answers for more detail.

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 3** version:

```
let lines = yourString.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
```

Nice and short.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate your content with "\n".

```
    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePathLib encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *rows = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for(int i =0;i<[rows count];i++)
        NSLog(@"Row %d: %@",i,[rows objectAtIndex:i]);
```

Comment: This also makes assumptions about line separators.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it:

```
    NSString* string = @"FOO\r\nBAR\r\r\n\rATZ\rELM327 v1.5";
    NSCharacterSet* newlineSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet* whitespaceSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSArray<NSString*>* components = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newlineSet];
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString* _Nullable string, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings){
        return [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceSet].length > 0;
    }];
    NSArray<NSString*>* lines = [components filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    [lines enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog( @"Line %u = '%@'", idx, obj );
    }];
```

Running this prints:

```
2017-10-24 15:26:05.380 Untitled 5[64977:3182818] Line 0 = 'FOO'
2017-10-24 15:26:05.380 Untitled 5[64977:3182818] Line 1 = 'BAR'
2017-10-24 15:26:05.380 Untitled 5[64977:3182818] Line 2 = 'ATZ'
2017-10-24 15:26:05.380 Untitled 5[64977:3182818] Line 3 = 'ELM327 v1.5'
```

It may not be the most efficient way (probably using an `NSScanner` would be faster), but it solves the problem here.

Comment: I like your answer the most because it both addresses many new-line scenarios, cleans up the output, and leaves doors open with NSScanner. I think it could even be nicely wrapped as an NSString Category NSString+lines and provide <NSArray *> * lines; method...