# Using String's enumerateLines function in Swift

Tags: swift

The `enumerateLines` function of Swift's `String` type is declared like this:

```
enumerateLines(body: (line: String, inout stop: Bool) -> ())
```

As I understand it, this declaration means: "enumerateLines is a function taking a closure, `body`, which is handed two variables, `line` and `stop`, and returns void."

According to the [Swift Programming Language book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), I believe I should thus be able to call `enumerateLines` in a nice terse fashion with a trailing closure, like this:

```
var someString = "Hello"

someString.enumerateLines()
{
    // Do something with the line here
}
```

..but that results in a compiler error:

`Tuple types '(line: String, inout stop: Bool)' and '()' have a different number of elements (2 vs. 0)`

So then I try explicitly putting in the arguments, and doing away with the trailing closure:

```
addressString.enumerateLines((line: String, stop: Bool)
{
    // Do something with the line here
})
```

...but that results in the error:

`'(() -> () -> $T2) -> $T3' is not identical to '(line: String.Type, stop: Bool.Type)'`

In short, no syntax that I've tried has resulted in anything that will successfully compile.

Could anybody point out the error in my understanding and provide a syntax that will work please? I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 4.

Comment: Isn't `enumerateLines` a method on `NSString`, not `String`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [closure expression syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_151) has the general form

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

In this case:

```
addressString.enumerateLines ({
    (line: String, inout stop: Bool) -> () in
    println(line)
})
```

Or, using the trailing closure syntax:

```
addressString.enumerateLines {
    (line: String, inout stop: Bool) in
    println(line)
}
```

Due to automatic type inference, this can be shortened to

```
addressString.enumerateLines {
    line, stop in
    println(line)
}
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
addressString.enumerateLines { (line, stop) in
    print(line)

    // Optionally:
    if someCondition { stop = true }
}
```

Or, if you don't need the "stop" parameter:

```
addressString.enumerateLines { (line, _) in
    print(line)
}
```