# How to split a string by new lines in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, newline

I have a string that I got from a text file.

Text file:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
...
```

I want to convert it to an array, one array element per line.

```
[ "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3", ... ]
```

Depending on how the file was saved, the string could take one of the following forms:

- `string = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n..."` where `\n` is the new line (line feed) character
- `string = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\n..."` where `\r` is the carriage return character.

As I understand it, `\n` is commonly used in Apple/Linux today, while `\r\n` is used in Windows.

How do I split a string at any line break to get a String array without any empty elements?

## Update

There are several solutions that work below. At this point I don't have any compelling reason to choose one as more correct than the others. Some factors that may influence choice could be (1) how "Swift" it is and (2) how fast it is for very long strings. You can provide feedback by upvoting one or more of them and/or leaving a comment.

#### [See my summarized answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062956/3681880)

Comment: probably as simple as `split(stringFromFile, { newLineChars.characterIsMember($0) }, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)`

Comment: @njzk2, I like the look of this, but I got an error "Cannot invoke `split` with an argument list of type `String, (unichar) -> Bool, maxSplit Int, allowEmptySlices: Bool)`" Could it be that the syntax has changed in Swift 2?

Comment: let test1 = "Line1\n\rLine2\n\rLine3\n\rLine4\nLine5\r\r\n\rLine6" 
let t1 =test1.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
let t2 = t1.filter{ $0 != ""}

works for me (Xcode 7, beta5)

Answer (score 134):

**Swift 5.2 or later**

You can split your `String` using the new `Character` property [`isNewline`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127014-isnewline?changes=late_5):

```
let sentence = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n"
let lines = sentence.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)
print(lines)   // "["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]\n"
```

---

You can also extend StringProtocol and create a lines instance property to break up the string lines into subsequences:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var lines: [SubSequence] { split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline) }
}
```

---

```
let sentence = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
for line in sentence.lines {
    print(line)
}
let lines = sentence.lines  // ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]
```

---

---

**Original Answer**

You can use String method **enumerateLines**:

> Enumerates all the lines in a string.

**Swift 3 or later**

```
let sentence = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n"
var lines: [String] = []
sentence.enumerateLines { line, _ in
    lines.append(line)
}
print(lines)   // "["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]\n"
```

---

```
extension String {
    var lines: [String] {
        var result: [String] = []
        enumerateLines { line, _ in result.append(line) }
        return result
    }
}
```

---

```
let sentence2 = "Line 4\nLine 5\nLine 6\n"
let sentence2Lines = sentence2.lines
print(sentence2Lines)    // "["Line 4", "Line 5", "Line 6"]\n"
let sentence3 = "Line 7\r\nLine 8\r\nLine 9\r\n"
let sentence3Lines = sentence3.lines
print(sentence3Lines)  // "["Line 7", "Line 8", "Line 9"]\n"
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923404-enumeratelines or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408459-enumeratelines doesn't say anything

Comment: Hmm you're right it doesn't say anything in the docs. Though, in Xcode 9 it shows it crossed out in red when used on a String. https://i.imgur.com/g6vOXoO.png Does the strike-through mean something else?

Comment: @RyanR What is the type of your `contents`? option click it. Try cleaning your project.

Comment: `var contents: String`

Comment: Try writing it manually. You probably have an issue somewhere else which it is causing the strange behavior.

Comment: Clean/build seems to have resolved the red strike-through on `enumerateLines`. Odd. Thanks!

Comment: `split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)` discards empty lines, good we still have `enumerateLines`

Comment: That’s the default of omittingEmptySubsequences (true). If you don’t want to omit just pass false

Comment: value of type 'Character' has no member 'isNewLine' - swift 5.2.2 on Linux, so I assume it's only for Apple-based Swift.

Comment: @Sebastian Swift is case sensitive. The correct is `isNewline`

Comment: @Sebastian Whaat is not achievable?

Answer (score 26):

in **Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0.1:**

Use NSString method **components(separatedBy:)**

```
let text = "line1\nline2"
let array = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
```

Or use String method **enumerateLines**, like `Leo Dabus`'s answer

Comment: `let array = text.components(separatedBy: .newlines)`

Comment: While `let array = text.components(separatedBy: .newlines)` looks clean and swifty it actually splits CRLF line terminators (`\r\n`) **TWICE**, leading to empty lines.

Comment: Any way to use components(separetdBy:) with CRLF line terminators?

Comment: @Raisen you just need to filter the empty strings after separating the new lines. You can also use the split method as I suggested above and map the resulting Substrings into Strings if needed.

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 2, the top-level `split` function is now a method on `CollectionType` (which each of `String`s "character views" conforms to). There are two versions of the method, you want the one that takes a closure as a predicate to indicate whether a given element should be treated as a separator.

You can get the character collection from the string as a collection of UTF16 characters using `string.utf16`, making them compatible with the `NSCharacterSet` APIs. This way, we can easily check inside the closure whether a given character in the string is a member of the newline character set.

It's worth noting that `split(_:)` will return a `SubSequence` of characters (basically a `Slice`), so it needs transforming back into an array of Strings which is generally more useful. I've done this below using `flatMap(String.init)` - the `UTF16View` initialiser on `String` is failable, so using `flatMap` will ignore any `nil` values that might be returned, ensuring you get an array of non-optional strings back.

So for a nice Swift-like way of doing this:

```
let str = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
let lines = str.utf16.split { newlineChars.characterIsMember($0) }.flatMap(String.init)
// lines = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]
```

What makes this nice is that the `split` method has a parameter `allowEmptySubsequences`, which ensures you don't receive any empty character sequences in the result. This is `false` by default, so you don't actually need to specify it at all.

#### Edit

If you want to avoid `NSCharacterSet` altogether, you can just as easily split the collection of unicode compliant `Character`s.

```
let lines = str.characters.split { $0 == "\n" || $0 == "\r\n" }.map(String.init)
```

Swift is able to treat `"\r\n"` as a single extended grapheme cluster, using it as a single `Character` for the comparison instead of creating a `String`. Also note that the initialiser for creating a string from a `Character` is non failable, so we can just use `map`.

Comment: I think you can use `map(String.init)` instead of `map { String($0)! }`.

Comment: @hennes You could, although since the `UTF16View` initialiser on `String` is failable, it will return and array of optionals strings (`[String?]`), and I don't think you can just force unwrap it directly. Better would be to use `flatMap(String.init)`, which will automatically ignore `nil`s and return an array of non-optionals. But thanks for the tip, I've updated the answer.

Comment: What will it mean for text that contains emoji or other characters that require surrogate encoding in utf16? Do I have to worry about big and little ending encoding now, too? Is there a "pure Swift" way of breaking at the newline without using `NSCharacterSet`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware (and as far as I have experimented), this shouldn't matter. `utf16` does decompose the string into those code units – splitting up the extended grapheme clusters – but after removing the newline characters the slices are reassembled into unicode strings anyway. It's perfectly fine to avoid `NSCharacterSet` and use the unicode compliant `Character` collection anyway – I've edited the answer with an example of this.

Comment: I had an incredibly hard time finding a good answer to this splitting problem but the code in your edit finally did the trick for me.
All the solutions using NSCharacterSet don't work in the IBM Sandbox.

Comment: @hnh Have you tried it, or read the explanation beneath the code in the edit? `"\r\n"` is expressible as a single `Character` value, and `str.characters` is a collection of `Character`s.

Comment: @Stuart Ups, you are right, srz. This is pretty strange :-)

Answer (score 9):

This answer is a summary of the other solutions already given. It comes from my [fuller answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062956/3681880), but it would be useful to have the actual method choices available here.

New lines are usually made with the `\n` character, but can also be made with `\r\n` (from files saved in Windows).

## Solutions

**1. `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`**

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
let lineArray = multiLineString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(newlineChars).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

If `filter` were not used, then `\r\n` would produce an empty array element because it gets counted as two characters and so separates the string twice at the same location.

**2. `split`**

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
let lineArray = multiLineString.utf16.split { newlineChars.characterIsMember($0) }.flatMap(String.init)
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

or

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
let lineArray = multiLineString.characters.split { $0 == "\n" || $0 == "\r\n" }.map(String.init)
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

Here `\r\n` gets counted as a single Swift character (an extended grapheme cluster)

**3. `enumerateLines`**

```
let multiLineString = "Line 1\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\n"
var lineArray = [String]()
multiLineString.enumerateLines { (line, stop) -> () in
    lineArray.append(line)
}
// "[Line 1, Line 2, Line 3]"
```

For more about the `enumerateLine` syntax, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096185/3681880) also.

## Notes:

- a multi line string would not usually mix both `\r\n` and `\n` but I am doing this here to show that these methods can handle both formats.
- [`NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/newlineCharacterSet) are newline characters defined as (U+000A–U+000D, U+0085), which include `\r` and `\n`.
- This answer is a summary of the answers to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021712/how-to-split-a-string-by-new-lines-in-swift). Read those answers for more detail.

Comment: I've added a different approach in case you want to include it.

Comment: @Cœur, good to know. When I have time, I'll study it more carefully.

Answer (score 7):

```
let test1 = "Line1\n\rLine2\nLine3\rLine4"
let t1 = test1.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
let t2 = t1.filter{ $0 != "" }
let t3 = t1.filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
```

Answer (score 3):

For the record, Swift's Foundation `CharacterSet` can be used within split:

#### alternative 1

```
extension String {
    var lines: [String] {
        return split { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: .newlines) != nil }.map(String.init)
    }
}
```

#### alternative 2

```
extension String {
    var lines: [String] {
        return split { CharacterSet.newlines.contains($0.unicodeScalars.first!) }.map(String.init)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I split a string at any line break to get a String array without any empty elements?

You were almost there - it's just the trailing closure which is different here:

```
let array = stringFromFile.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
```

Which is the same as:

```
let newLineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet() // newline characters defined as (U+000A–U+000D, U+0085)
let array = stringFromFile.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(newLineChars).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
```

ETA: removed unnecessary extra brackets at trailing closure

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:**

I would recommend to first save your CSV into  string if you haven't already done it, then "clean" the string by removing unnecessary carriage returns

```
        let dataString = String(data: yourData!, encoding: .utf8)!

        var cleanFile = dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "\n")
        cleanFile = cleanFile.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n")
```

Above will give you a string with a most desirable format, then you can separate the string using \n as your separator:

```
        let csvStrings = cleanFile.components(separatedBy: ["\n"])
```

Now you have an array of 3 items like:

**["Line1","Line2","Line3"]**

I am using a CSV file and after doing this, I am splitting items into components, so if your items were something like:

["Line1,Line2,Line3","LineA,LineB,LineC"]

```
        let component0 = csvStrings[0].components(separatedBy: [","]) // ["Line1","Line2","Line3"]
        let component1 = csvStrings[1].components(separatedBy: [","]) // ["LineA","LineB","LineC"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```swift
let getName = "Davender+Verma"
let cleanFile = getName.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "+\n")
self.upcomingViewPetName.text = cleanFile

// Output
Davender+
verma
```

Option 2:

```swift
let getName = "Davender+Verma"
let cleanFile = getName.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "\n")
self.upcomingViewPetName.text = cleanFile

//Output:
Davender
verma
```