# How can I split a multi-line string literal with optional variables in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, macos, cocoa, swift4

I’m trying to get the index of an element contained in a certain class that matches a global variable. Searching for nodes with CSS queries gives me a list with potential matching elements, but — as [Kanna’s documentation](http://tid-kijyun.github.io/Kanna/tutorials/v2/searching.html#searching-an-htmlxml-document) points out — such queries return `XPathObjects` that act as arrays. The only way I can see to get index values from said list is to convert it from an array into a string, which can then be split by new lines; however, I can’t seem to get the list to take a string value. The relevant part of a typical compile session log follows:

```
Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® (2 pack)
Orange
Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® Folio Toujours (2 Pack)
Blue
…
```

I’ve tried three methods suggested by one poster in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021712/how-to-split-a-string-by-new-lines-in-swift/32021850#32021850) to concatenate the above output:

1). componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet

```
for node in (doc?.css("a[class^='product-link']"))! {
    let multiLineString = node.text!
    let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
    let lineArray = multiLineString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(newlineChars).filter{!  $0.isEmpty}
}
```

Ideally, this would print `[Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® (2 pack), Orange, Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® Folio Toujours (2 Pack), Blue]`; it raises an error instead. Clicking `fix` leads to another error — and another one.

2). split

```
for node in (doc?.css("a[class^='product-link']"))! { 
    let multiLineString = node.text!
    let newlineChars = NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()
    let lineArray = multiLineString.utf16.split { newlineChars.characterIsMember($0) }.flatMap(String.init)
}
```

Yields the same result as `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'CharacterSet'` -> `fix` -> error -> `fix` -> error.

3). enumerateLines

```
for node in (doc?.css("a[class^='product-link']"))! {             
    let multiLineString = node.text!
    var lineArray = [String]()
    multiLineString.enumerateLines { (line, stop) -> () in
        lineArray.append(line)
    }
}
```

This solution actually builds, but it returns each list item as `function()`.

These methods work when I try them on simple multi-line string literals in Playgrounds, but for some reason they don't work on the output above. The easiest way to solve this problem would be to use `func index(of element: Element) -> Int?`, but doing so gives me a `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Character'` error. I'm new to Swift, so if anyone with more experience could suggest alternative approaches to this problem, I would much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your larger goal, this is how you should go about solving the problem:

```
var prodIndex = 0
var testProd = "Prod" // to be replaced by user input

for node in (doc?.css("a[class^='name-link']"))! {
    let words = testProd.split(separator: " ")
    if prodIndex % 2 == 0 {
        if node.text! == testProd {
            print("FOUND: " + testProd)
        }

        prodIndex += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is outdated. The first method in Swift 3+ is

```
let newlineChars = CharacterSet.newlines
let lineArray = multiLineString.components(separatedBy: newlineChars).filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
```

To put the text in one line use

```
let oneLine = multiLineString.components(separatedBy: newlineChars).filter{ !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
```

Comment: This gives me: `["Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® (2 pack)"]\n["Orange"]\n["Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® Folio Toujours (2 Pack)"]\n["Blue"]`. How do I get them on the same line? Splitting by newline just replicates the issues demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to say you want

```
Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® (2 pack)
Orange
Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® Folio Toujours (2 Pack)
Blue
```

as a single line string correct?

```
for node in (doc?.css("a[class^='product-link']"))! {
    // suggestion: use a guard here, it's good practice to safely unwrap optionals
    guard let multiLineString = node.text else { return }

    let lineArray = multiLineString.components(separatedBy: .newlines).joined(separator: " ")
 }
```

prints: `Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® (2 pack) Orange Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® Folio Toujours (2 Pack) Blue`

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I'm still getting my original output of `Kazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® (2 pack)\nOrange\nKazuo®/Ishiguro® Auprès® Folio Toujours (2 Pack)\nBlue`. Could this be a system issue?

Comment: Try switching `.newlines` with `”\n”`

Comment: Hmmm, there maybe something missing from the question that isn’t obvious out because nothing is standing out to m on why this should’ve work.

Comment: How are you handling `lineArray` once it’s assigned?

Comment: When I run `print(lineArray)` it gives me the same output as above.

Comment: It is actually really bugging me that this is not working. If you want, my twitter is listed on account, if you want you can direct message me there and we can try a more in detail approach to this.