# How to get the full line range for a given character range in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, macos, line-numbers

Apple has an old example how to get the range of a whole line, given a particular character range:

#### [Counting Lines of Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

In order to obtain the full line range of the first line, they call the following *Objective-C* function:

```
[string lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)]
```

I tried to implement the same thing in *Swift*, but I can't make it work because the method signature has changed:

```
string.lineRange(for: NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
```

throws a compiler error:

> `Argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') does not conform to expected type 'RangeExpression'`

`RangeExpression` is some weird protocol I haven't really understood in its entirety. However, I figured  that `Range<Bound>` conforms to it, so I tried the following:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
textView.string.lineRange(for: Range<Int>(range)!)
```

This time I get another compiler error:

> `Generic parameter 'R' could not be inferred`

I couldn't find any generic parameter `R`, neither in `Range`, nor in `RangeExpression`.

#### What's this all about and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lineRange(for:)` (essentially) expects a range of `String.Index`, not a range of integers. Here is a simple example:

```
let string = "Line1\nLine2"

// Find the full range of the line containing the first "1":
if let range = string.range(of: "1") {
    let lineRange = string.lineRange(for: range)
    print(string[lineRange]) // Line1
}
```

The actual parameter is a generic parameter of type `R : RangeExpression, R.Bound == String.Index`, which means that you can also pass *partial ranges* like `string.startIndex...` or `..<string.endIndex`.

The Swift version of the [Objective-C sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

```
NSString *string;
unsigned numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [string length];
for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < stringLength; numberOfLines++)
    index = NSMaxRange([string lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]);
```

would be

```
let string = "Line1\nLine2"

var index = string.startIndex
var numberOfLines = 0
while index != string.endIndex {
    let range = string.lineRange(for: index..<index)
    numberOfLines += 1
    index = range.upperBound
}

print(numberOfLines)
```

Here `index..<index` takes the role of `NSMakeRange(index, 0)`.

If the purpose is just to count (or enumerate) the total number of lines then an alternative is to use

```
string.enumerateLines(invoking: { (line, _) in
    // ...
})
```

instead (compare [How to split a string by new lines in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021712/how-to-split-a-string-by-new-lines-in-swift/32021850#32021850)).