# Is there a short hand way to loop through an array and add values to another array?

Tags: swift

Is there a short hand way of doing something like this in Swift?

```swift
var serviceTypes = [String]()
for menu in menus {
    if let serviceType = menu.serviceType {
        serviceTypes += [serviceType]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since you're only adding to the other array if the `serviceType` is non-nil, use [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap).

If you're using Swift 5.2 or later, [you can do this with `KeyPath`s](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md):

```
let serviceTypes = menus.compactMap(\.serviceType)
```

If you're using a version of Swift prior to 5.2, you can use a closure:

```
let serviceTypes = menus.compactMap { $0.serviceType }
```

Comment: There is no need to use a closure `compactMap(\.serviceType)` you can use the KeyPath

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus, I had no idea you could use keypaths like that as of Swift 5.2. I'll update my answer to include that!

Comment: You are welcome KeyPaths where introduced in Swift 4

Comment: Yes but this functionality was not introduced until [Swift 5.2](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md).

Comment: Yes the use with compactMap was added later

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32021850/2303865 you can use it with split method as well but you need to disambiguate including the parameter name

Answer (score 1):

`map()` is your friend! (And it has friends, `flatMap()` and `compactMap()`.)

```
var serviceTypes = menus.compactMap {$0.serviceType}
```

More info here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/205/whats-the-difference-between-map-flatmap-and-compactmap